# Webdriverio using async/await - What is recommended?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am running my functional tests using [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io). I can get the WebdriverIO tests to pass even without `async/await`. But I read some articles that `async/await` is the best way of coding javascript to handle promises.

I am new to Javascript and pretty lost on promises. What is the best way to code in WebdriverIO (*using async/await, or not* | e.g: *turn sync off in config and use this?*)

The `wdio.conf.js` config file states the following:

```
// By default WebdriverIO commands are executed in a synchronous way using
// the wdio-sync package. If you still want to run your tests in an async 
// e.g. using promises you can set the sync option to false.
//
sync: true
```

Comment: Please, add your code to the question

Comment: I rephrased my question. I am trying to figure out `is using async/await in webdriverio the best way of coding by turning sync off in configuration file or not using it by turning sync on in that file`

Comment: Don't believe every article you read. If you come from a traditional,  sequential programming environment, then stay with `sync: true`. Else, if you want to excel at JS & using Promises, then go `sync: false`.  It's just flavor ... w/e *floats your boat*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebdriverIO still uses async/await in the background, it just handles it for you. I'd definitely recommend using 'sync' mode, as it reduces the verbosity of your tests.

Comment: Can you give some example to understand further

Comment: There's good documentation/examples here: https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async.html

Comment: This answer definitely didn't age well: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/6702